# Is it possible to install Windows 8.1 Preview to test on a hard drive where Ubuntu is installed, then remove windows when done?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

Well, recently I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on an portable hard drive to run certain programs on that don't run fast on Windows 8 (Minecraft). I have really started to like Ubuntu, but I also want to test Windows 8.1 Preview on it and get my Dad to try it. My question is that how do I install it without touching Ubuntu, boot into Windows 8.1 or Ubuntu easily, and be able to remove Windows 8.1 without damaging Ubuntu. Also, how would I do this with other Linux distro installs. Sorry for the long question. I'll list my computer specs below. Thanks, and have a good day!

Computer Specs:

- Compaq Presario CQ60-615DX
- Ubuntu running on a Trancend StoreJet 500 GB portable hard drive
- 2 GB RAM

The partitioning setup is:

- 500 MB Boot partition
- 282.19 GB partition where Ubuntu is installed
- 4 GB Swap partition
- 183.10 GB unallocated space

Comment: This is more of a windows8 question than anything. At least make sure you make a grub-rescue CD, so if windows8 makes itself the default to boot, you can get Ubuntu back.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I can figure out Windows Setup so that should be fine (I Installed Windows 8 To My laptop itself). Where would I get a grub-rescue CD if I could ask?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, just follow the instructions on dual booting windows 8 and ubuntu. but remember once you installed windows it overwrites master boot record and if you uninstall it, you'll have some trouble getting back to ubuntu (there is no grub any more).

Another way is to use VirtualBox but I don't if it supports windows 8.1